# Using Lookup to find latest entry in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, dataextensions

*First, Explanation:*

So, I have a Data Extension and every time a visitor on our website visits a product several times, that product ID is sent to a Data Extension.

My Data Extension has these fields:

`SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, SHA256, Country Code, ListImageType, ID`

By using Lookup I'm able to find out if each visitor has shown interest in a certain product and show them that product or related products.

But if a visitor have shown interest in several products over time, I only want to show them the latest product.. or products related to that product.

*So, Question:*

**I want use Lookup to return a product ID by searching for a visitor ID. But if the visitor appears more than once in my Data Extension, I only want to return the latest entry. How can I accomplish this - can I perhaps alter my code to search from 'the bottom of' my Data Extension?**

*My Lookup:*

```
VAR @ID
SET @ID = Lookup('ProductInterestTriggerDE','ID','SHA256',v(SHA256))
```

Comment: Is there not a date field in your data extension?  You'd need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest adding a date field to your data extension -- one that's nullable and defaulted to today's date.  Once that's done, you can leverage the [**LookupOrderedRows()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) function for rows added from that point forward:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @SHA256, @i

set @SHA256 = AttributeValue("SHA256")
set @numRowsToReturn = 1 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("ProductInterestTriggerDE", @numRowsToReturn, "CreatedDate desc", "SHA256", @SHA256)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    set @row = row(@rows,1) 
    set @ID = field(@row,"ID")
    set @ListImageType = field(@row,"ListImageType")
    set @CountryCode = field(@row,"Country Code")

    output(concat("<br>ID: ", @ID))
    output(concat("<br>ListImageType: ", @ListImageType))
    output(concat("<br>CountryCode: ", @CountryCode))

else

output(concat("No rows found"))

endif 

]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, helpful as always :)
I'll give this solution a try, and get back to you.

Comment: What you've suggested above was a super solution. Easy and quick to implement and working like a charm. Super advise! Thanks